# Spring Security - Authorize Request for certain URL & HTTP-Method using HttpSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jhipster, matcher

Is there any way to authorize a `POST` http-request to a specific URL using `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity` ?

I'm using `HttpSecurity` as:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
            .key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key"))
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
            .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/api/subscriptions").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
}
```

I would like to allow only `POST` requests to the path `"/api/subscription"`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Take a look at [Spring Data REST + Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security) which has

```
http
  .httpBasic().and()
  .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/employees").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
```

Comment: Updated to exclude the csrf disable which was copied in from the referenced code. This was also discussed in an another answer

Comment: Why you exclude?

Answer (score 42):

## TL;DR

Since [**Spring 6.0**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/whats-new.html) release configuration methods <del>`antMatchers()`</del>, <del>`mvcMathcers()`</del> and <del>`regexMatchers()`</del> have been **removed** from the API.

And several flavors of `requestMatchers()` method has been provided as a replacement.

> [gh-11939](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11939) - **Remove deprecated** antMatchers, mvcMatchers, regexMatchers helper methods from Java Configuration. **Instead, use** `requestMatchers` or `HttpSecurity#securityMatchers`.

Also, an overloaded method `authorizeHttpRequests()` was introduced to replace **Deprecated** <del>`authorizeRequests()`</del>.

Even if you're using an earlier Spring version in your project and not going to update to *Spring 6* very soon, `antMatchers()` **isn't** the best tool you can choose for securing requests to your application.

While applying security rules using `antMatchers()` you need to be very careful because if you secure let's say path `"/foo"` these restrictions **wouldn't** be applied to other aliases of this path like `"/foo/"`, `"/foo.thml"`. As a consequence, it's very easy to misconfigure security rules and **introduce a vulnerability** (*for instance, a path that is supposed to be accessible only for Admins becomes available for any authenticated user, it's surprising that none of the answers above mentions this*).

## Spring 6.0 - [`requestMatchers()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(java.lang.String...))

According to the documentation, the recommended way to restrict access to certain URL since `5.8` is to use [`HttpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)), which as well as its predecessor comes in two flavors:

- A parameterless version, which returns an object responsible for configuring the requests (*to be precise, an instance of [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.html) lengthy-name class*). So we can chain `requestMatchers()` calls directly on it.
- And the second one expecting an instance of the `Customizer` interface which allow to apply enhanced DSL (*domain-specific language*), by using lambda expressions. See [*this post*](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/21/spring-security-lambda-dsl), it uses outdated matching methods but nicely illustrates the key idea of Lambda DSL, which makes the configuration more intuitive to read by visually grouping configuration options and eliminates the need to use method `and()`.

Which version of `authorizeHttpRequests()` to use is a *stylistic choice* (both are valid and supported in `6.0`).

Now `requestMatchers()` are coming into play, this method has four overloaded versions which can replace any of the removed matching methods:

- [`requestMatchers( String ... )`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(java.lang.String...)) - expects a varargs of `String` patterns. This matcher uses the same rules for matching as Spring MVC. I.e. it would act in the same way as old `mvcMatchers()`, so that pattern `/foo` would match all existing aliases of that path like `"/foo"`, `"/foo/"`, `"/foo.html"`. All other versions of `requestMatchers()` have the same matching behavior, it eliminates the possibility of misconfiguration, which was an Achilles' heel of `antMatchers()`. **Note** that the corresponding restriction (`hasRole()`, `access()`, etc.) would be applied to any matching request regardless of its HttpMethod.

*Example:*

```
.requestMatchers("/foo/*").hasRole("ADMIN") // only authenticated user with role ADMIN can access path /foo/something
.requestMatchers("/bar/*", "/baz/*").hasRole("ADMIN") // only authenticated requests to paths /foo/something and /baz/something  are allowed
```

- [`requestMatchers( HttpMethod )`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod)) - expects an `HttpMethod` as argument. The corresponding restriction (`hasRole()`, `access()`, etc.) would be applied to any request handled by the current `SecurityFilterChain` having specified HttpMethod. If `null` provided as an argument, any request would match.

*Example:*

```
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/bar/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN") // any authenticated POST-requests should from an ADMIN or USER are allowed
```

- [`requestMatchers( HttpMethod, String ... )`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,java.lang.String...)) - this method combines the previous two, it allows to specify an `HttpMethod` and one or more `String` patterns.

*Example:*

```
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/bar/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN") // any POST-request should be authenticatd
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/baz/**").hasRole( "ADMIN") // only ADMINs can issue DELETE-requests to these paths
```

- [`requestMatchers( RequestMatcher ... )`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher...)) - the last version is probably the most flexible one, it allows to provide an arbitrary number of combines [`RequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html) instances. We don't need to implement this interface ourself (unless there's special need), there are several implementations available out of the box including `RegexRequestMatcher` (which can be used to replace outdated `regexMatchers()`).

*Example:*

```
.requestMatchers(new RegexRequestMatcher("/foo/bar", "POST")).authenticated()
```

## Example - Addressing the Original problem

> I would like to allow `POST` requests only to the `"/api/subscription"` path.

For that we would need to use this flavor of [`requestMatchers(HttpMethod, String...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,java.lang.String...)) which allows to specify HTTP-method and pattern for path `"/api/subscription"`.

**Reminder:** <del>`WebSecurityConfigureAdapter`</del> is [deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) since Spring Security `5.7` release, and now `HttpSecurity` is being configured through `SecurityFilterChain` which should be defined as Bean.

Here's how we can secure requests to paths defined in the question using Spring 6 and lambda DSL:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        
        return http
            // other configuration options
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authCustomizer -> authCustomizer
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/subscriptions").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                    "/api/register", "/api/register", "/api/authenticate"
                ).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            )
            .build();
    }
}
```

#### Note

- Security rules are being evaluated from top to bottom, the first matching rule would be applied. Make sure that rules are declared in the proper order.
- Apply **deny-by-default** policy. While an application evolves, new paths get introduced, and there's a possibility that during these changes your colleagues might forget to update security restrictions and some end point would appear to be unprotected. To avoid that in each `SecurityFilterChain` (*we can declare more than one filter chain, to configure different parts of the system and specify their order*) as the last constraint you can introduce a matcher that encompasses all unspecified URLs governed by this `SecurityFilterChain` like `"/foo/**"` (i.e. all paths under /foo) applying either `authenticated()` or `denyAll()`. And `SecurityFilterChain` which would be considered as the last one to handle the request should cut out request to all unspecified URLs from the root with `requestMatchers("/**").denyAll()`. That configuration would prevent both unauthenticated access and disclosing what paths are valid in your system. If a newly introduced endpoint is not accessible (*for instance it should be permitted for non-authorize request*) would be obvious for your colleague immediately during development process. It's way safer to specify what should be open and keep everything else closed by default.

## Spring 5.7 and Earlier

As I've said at beginning even with an Spring version `antMatchers()` because by using them you can end up with intoducing Broken access control valnarability.

Here's one more related link: [*Deprecate trailing slash match*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28552).

Instead consider applying either [`mvcMathcers()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.9.RELEASE/api/) which as it name suggests uses Spring MVC matching rules, or regex-based [`regexMatchers()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.9.RELEASE/api/). Both `mvcMathcers()` and `regexMatchers()` have an overloaded version that allows specifing an HTTP-method.

Here how to secure the API from the question using `mvcMathcers()` and Spring Security 5.2 Lambda DSL:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain1(HttpSecurity http) {
        
        return http
            // other configuration options
            .authorizeRequests(authCustomizer -> authCustomizer
                .mvcMatchers(
                    "/api/register", "/api/register", "/api/authenticate"
                ).permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/subscriptions").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .regexMatchers("/**").denyAll()
            )
            .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is a bit old but I don't believe disabling csrf support is an acceptable answer.  I had this same problem but don't feel good able using csrf.disable().  Instead I added the following line at the bottom of the page inside the form tags.

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Comment: Good point, I will update my answer as the csrf part is not relevant to the original question. This was taken as is from a documented example of doing rest calls rather than web as seen here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/rest/security/src/main/java/example/springdata/rest/security/SecurityConfiguration.java