# Allow get, but not post, put for some role

Tags: spring, spring-security

I use spring boot and spring security.

i add security based on url like this

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()                                                                
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            
        .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
        .and()
    // ...
    .formLogin();
```

Is there a way to authorise only get, post, put... on url for some role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass method as the first argument of `antMatchers()` method:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Link to [API for AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.antMatchers()](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#antMatchers-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-java.lang.String...-)

P.S. Similar question: [Spring security authorize request for url & method using HttpSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907030/spring-security-authorize-request-for-url-method-using-httpsecurity)