# Updating to Spring Security 6.0 - replacing Removed and Deprecated functionality for securing requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0 and Spring Security 6.0.

I've found that method for securing requests `authorizeRequests()` has been deprecated. And also method `antMatchers()` and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation has removed. How can I upgrade my security configuration?

*My code:*

```java
package org.sid.securityservice.config;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    private RsakeysConfig rsakeysConfig;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SecurityConfig(RsakeysConfig rsakeysConfig, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.rsakeysConfig = rsakeysConfig;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    //@Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService inMemoryUserDetailsManager(){
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("user1").password(passwordEncoder.encode("1234")).authorities("USER").build(),
                User.withUsername("user2").password(passwordEncoder.encode("1234")).authorities("USER").build(),
                User.withUsername("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("1234")).authorities("USER","ADMIN").build()
        );
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth->auth.antMatchers("/token/**").permitAll())
                .authorizeRequests(auth->auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(sess->sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsakeysConfig.publicKey()).build();
    }
    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(){
        JWK jwk= new RSAKey.Builder(rsakeysConfig.publicKey()).privateKey(rsakeysConfig.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource= new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
    }

}
```

Here's what IDE shows me (*struck out* `authorizeRequests()` *and missing* `antMatchers()` *highlighted in red*):

[image]

Answer (score 160, accepted):

In Spring Security 6.0,
`antMatchers()` as well as other configuration methods for securing requests
(*namely* `mvcMatchers()` *and* `regexMatchers()`) have been **removed** from the API.

An overloaded method [`requestMatchers()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(java.lang.String...)) was introduced as a uniform mean for securing requests. The flavors of `requestMatchers()` facilitate all the ways of restricting requests that were supported by the removed methods.

Also, method <del>`authorizeRequests()`</del> has been **deprecated** and shouldn't be used anymore. A recommended replacement - [`authorizeHttpRequests()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)) (*you can find more information regarding these changes [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74633151/17949945)*).

That's how your `SecurityFilterChain` might be defined in Spring Security 6.0:

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/token/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .build();
}
```

Regarding deprecated annotation <del>`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`</del> it was replaced with [`@EnableMethodSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.7.0/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableMethodSecurity.html). The rationale behind this change is that with `@EnableMethodSecurity` property `prePostEnabled` needed to enable use of `@PreAuthorize/@PostAuthorize` and `@PreFilter/@PostFilter` is by default set to `true`.

So you no longer need to write `prePostEnabled = true`, just annotating your configuration class with `@EnableMethodSecurity` would be enough.

Comment: @JamesGrey `conr()` is not present in the configuration you've posted as well. I'm not aware of the allowed origins and headers in your application.

Comment: ok, I checked. I can control cors() success.

Comment: @JamesGrey Ok, if you would need information on configuring CORS, check this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/integrations/cors.html).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko - This line seems not to work though -> `.requestMatchers("/token/**").permitAll()`. When upgraded to Spring 6.0, the `/token/**` path requires authentication. Is there anything else that needs to be added to allow the `permitAll`? Thanks!

Comment: @securecurve You can't apply security roles created via `requestMatchers()` in isolation (and there's nothing wrong `requestMatchers(...).permitAll()`. There's something else in your security configuration that causes the problem. In order to tell what exactly, you have to provide a sufficient problem description, firstly you need to show the **current security configuration** and describe the **failing behavior** (preferably in the form of [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). I would advise opening a new question for that.

Comment: @securecurve, I have the same problem, maybe you should also watch my question in case anyone answers....

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75080739/spring-security-6-post-requests-are-unauthorised-with-permitall

Comment: @OctaviaAdler Your problem has nothing to do with `requestMatchers()`. Learn about [**CSRF-protection**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html) mechanism, which guards the state of the application against undesired changes (therefore only mutating HTTP-methods `POST`, `PATCH`, etc. would trigger CSRF-protection, but `GET` which is supposed to be idempotent wouldn't). CSRF-protection is enabled by **default** in Spring Security. Usually, when an application is intended to be used only by *non-browser clients*, you want to disable CSRF-protection.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, thanks for your replay, yes, it has to do with CSRF protection, but I send the CSRF token, so yeah, I still don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: @OctaviaAdler Thanks for the reference to your question. After several tests, there was nothing wrong with `requestMatchers`- Thanks, @Alexander!

Comment: The samples mention in spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html still use `antMatcher`

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi You're confusing [`AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html#antMatcher(java.lang.String)) (an overloaded static method added with Spring Security 5.8) and `antMatchers()` (*have a careful look at the link you've referenced*). `AntPathRequestMatcher` is one of the implementations of `RequestMatcher` interface provided by Spring Security (*there are few more like* `RegexRequestMatcher`).

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi `RequestMatcher` instance can be used while defining security rules with [`requestMatchers()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#requestMatchers(org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher...)) and [`HttpSecurity.securityMatcher()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#securityMatcher(org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher)).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Maybe you need to declare any permitAll requestMatcher before authenticated or fullyAuthenticated matchers.

Comment: @Jamali That what exactly what the very first specified authorization rule does `requestMatchers("/token/**").permitAll()`.

Comment: The new system is so much better wow.

Answer (score 3):

'csrf()' is deprecated since version 6.1 and marked for removal solutions:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        contentSecurityConfig(http);
        AntPathRequestMatcher[] requestMatchers = getAntPathRequestMatchers();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(requestMatchers).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()))
                ).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has any problems with the depreciation of jwt in the spring security 6

`oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)`

The following worked for me

`oauth2ResourceServer(spec -> spec.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))`