# The method antMatchers(String) is undefined for the type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

```
package com.codewitheshan.blog.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.codewitheshan.blog.security.CustomUserDetailService;
import com.codewitheshan.blog.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.codewitheshan.blog.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable()          
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        http.addFilterBefore(this.jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(this.customUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
            return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
        }   
}
```

[There is error showing in antMatchers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxJJo.png)

**I'm getting an error for "antMatchers". It is not recognised. I have tied searching but did not get any thing related to this.
Error is:
The method antMatchers(String) is undefined for the type AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry

How to fix it? **

Comment: have a look here: [updating-to-spring-security-6-0-replacing-removed-and-deprecated-functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683225/updating-to-spring-security-6-0-replacing-removed-and-deprecated-functionality)

Answer (score 8):

This method has changed to :

```java
.requestMatchers({your-matcher})
```

So, in your case :

```java
http
    .csrf()
    .disable()          
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login").permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    // ...
```

More information : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html

I hope this has helped you

Answer (score -1):

```
private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {"/authentification/**"};
    
//It gives authorization to users to authenticate through this url   
   return httpSecurity
  .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())            
  .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
  .requestMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
  .anyRequest()
  .authenticated())
  .build();
```

Comment: Please note that this is the English-only version of stack overflow. This helps all readers from everywhere to understand questions and answers in a common languate.