# The method antMatchers() is undefined for the type AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizedUrl

Tags: spring, boot

```
package com.nikola.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration //klasata mora da bide anotirana so @Configuration bidejki e configuration klasa
@EnableWebSecurity //so anotiranje na @EnableWebSecurity kazuvame deka vo ovaa klasa ke implementirame se
//za security za nasata aplikacija
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception  {
        
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()//authoriziraj gi
        .antMatchers("/","index","/css/*","/js/*")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()//sekoj request 
        .authenticated()//mora da bide avtenticiran 
        .and()//i
        .httpBasic();//mehanizmot koi sakame da go koristime e http Basic
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Hello
I am trying to follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=her_7pa0vrg
But i got an error: Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method antMatchers(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry   ApplicationSecurityConfig.java  /Spring-Boot-Security-Tutorial-NovoVideo/src/main/java/com/nikola/security  line 19 Java Problem

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [updating-to-spring-security-6-0-replacing-removed-and-deprecated-functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683225/updating-to-spring-security-6-0-replacing-removed-and-deprecated-functionality)