# How to set SessionCreationPolicy in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to set `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` but `sessionManagement()` is deprecated and marked for removal. How can I set it?

The deprecated method is below:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());

   http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

   http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

   return http.build();
}
```

[deprecated message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaPHd.png)

Comment: Please share your message as the plain text format not as image

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#sessionManagement()) and [official examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#stateless-authentication), you should use `Customizer` approach, like:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll())
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
        .build();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem.

In Spring Security 6.0, `antMatchers()` as well as other configuration methods for securing requests (namely `mvcMatchers()` and `regexMatchers()`) have been removed from the API.

The solution to this problem is in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74688849/15360925).