# Updating to Spring Security 6.0 - failing unit tests after the refactoring the source code - getting "Access Denied"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0 and Spring Security 6.0. The old version of a configuration file looks like this:

```
import somecompany.verification.components.PreAuthFilter;
import somecompany.verification.environments.VerificationProperties;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@AutoConfiguration(after = {VerificationProperties.class, VerificationConfig.class})
public class VerificationSecurityConfig {

    private final PreAuthFilter preAuthFilter;
    private final VerificationProperties verificationProperties;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain verificationFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("Configuring endpoints security access");

        var pathExpressions = verificationProperties.getPathExpressions();

        return http.requestMatchers().antMatchers(pathExpressions)
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(pathExpressions).fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .addFilter(preAuthFilter)
                .build();
    }
}
```

After moving to Spring boot 3.0.0 and respectively spring security 6.0.0. I refactored the method like this:

```
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain verificationFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("Configuring endpoints security access");

        var pathExpressions = verificationProperties.getPathExpressions();

        http.securityMatchers(request -> {
                    request.requestMatchers(pathExpressions);
                })
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
                    request.requestMatchers(pathExpressions).fullyAuthenticated();
                });
        http.sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS));
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.addFilter(preAuthFilter);
        return http.build();
    }
```

Looking at this : [Updating to Spring Security 6.0 - replacing Removed and Deprecated functionality for securing requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683225/updating-to-spring-security-6-0-replacing-removed-and-deprecated-functionality)

and the links, provided there, I changed

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

with

```
@EnableMethodSecurity
```

and added the following property in the test application.properties file:

```
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

because this is the path expression "/api/**/*".

But since then, some of the unit tests are failing.
Here is one unit test, which uses jwt token:

```
  @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void getForCustomer_Forbidden_WhenUserIsNotCustomer() {
        var token = createToken(AZN, ABS_KUNDENNUMMER, MFA.getAscValue(), CIM_UUID, INTERESSENT);

        mvc.perform(get("/api/some/endpoint/customer")
                        .with(x509("/testclient.crt"))
                        .header(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token))
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }
```

After debugging, I found, that the issue comes from the fact, that the method authenticate

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
```

of the class PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider

is called with no certificate

```
PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken [Principal=PreAuthPrincipal(certificate=null, jwToken=de.company.portal.security.jwt.validation.azd.AzdJWToken@6a4f7c17, name=-::-::allowedJwtUser), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
```

and I am wondering why....

Here is the stack trace:

```
authenticate:78, PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth)
authenticate:182, ProviderManager (org.springframework.security.authentication)
doAuthenticate:200, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth)
doFilter:142, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth)
wrapFilter:185, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:173, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:134, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:107, LogoutFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout)
doFilter:93, LogoutFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout)
wrapFilter:185, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:173, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:134, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doHeadersAfter:90, HeaderWriterFilter (org.springframework.security.web.header)
doFilterInternal:75, HeaderWriterFilter (org.springframework.security.web.header)
doFilter:116, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
wrapFilter:185, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:173, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:134, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:69, SecurityContextHolderFilter (org.springframework.security.web.context)
doFilter:116, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
wrapFilter:185, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:173, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:134, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:62, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async)
doFilter:116, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
wrapFilter:185, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:173, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:134, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:42, DisableEncodeUrlFilter (org.springframework.security.web.session)
doFilter:116, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
wrapFilter:185, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:-1, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter$$Lambda$1456/0x00000001367d1a38 (org.springframework.security.web)
lambda$wrap$0:278, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:-1, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation$$Lambda$1457/0x00000001367d1c80 (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:170, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:134, ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:233, FilterChainProxy (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:191, FilterChainProxy (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:132, SecurityMockMvcConfigurer$DelegateFilter (org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup)
doFilter:132, MockFilterChain (org.springframework.mock.web)
perform:201, MockMvc (org.springframework.test.web.servlet)
getForCustomer_Success_WhenUserIsCustomer:107, VerificationIntegrationTest (company.verification)
```

I checked and in the current version of the implementation the "authenticate" method of the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider is called with the argument Authentication containing the certificate.

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix this?
I add logs from the console, when I set
logging.level.org.springframework.security = TRACE

```
********************************************************************
**********        Security debugging is enabled.       *************
**********    This may include sensitive information.  *************
**********      Do not use in a production system!     *************
********************************************************************


2023-10-05T13:42:42.712+03:00  INFO 9595 --- [           main] d.a.m.v.VerificationIntegrationTest      : Started VerificationIntegrationTest in 3.949 seconds (process running for 6.741)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.406+03:00  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2023-10-05T13:42:43.406+03:00  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2023-10-05T13:42:43.407+03:00  INFO 9595 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-10-05T13:42:43.487+03:00  INFO 9595 --- [           main] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/api/some/endpoint/customer':

org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest@5dd2ea0a

servletPath:
pathInfo:/api/some/endpoint/customer
headers: 
Authorization: Bearer <somebearer>

Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  PreAuthFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


2023-10-05T13:42:43.489+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/secured/nonapi/endpoint/**'], Mvc [pattern='/unsecured/nonapi/endpoint/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@118cbded, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4cc26df, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@5aa6da2, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@708dfe10, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@194911c1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@121ddca4, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@13908f9c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@329b331f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7848321e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5c8b10b4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@625264ed, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@46c662f2]] (1/3)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.491+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/health'], Mvc [pattern='/prometheus']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@2e159116, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@d1f23a0, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@280d5a82, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6cc8adff, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6efd0a6e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@28bd5015, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1a34a51e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@333a44f2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2976ca51, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6b2e9db2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@120411ec, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@30228de7]] (2/3)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.492+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/api/**/*']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1d0b447b, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4de158ca, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2f61de04, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3c3cd13a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@48d31d25, de.company.verification.components.PreAuthFilter@4f2fdf3d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5f5a33ed, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5b59c3d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@d180961, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@56b751b1, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@405603b6, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6f65a203]] (3/3)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.493+03:00 DEBUG 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/some/endpoint/customer
2023-10-05T13:42:43.495+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.510+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.512+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.513+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.514+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.514+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-10-05T13:42:43.514+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking PreAuthFilter (6/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.515+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-10-05T13:42:43.547+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.548+03:00 DEBUG 9595 --- [           main] p.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider : PreAuthenticated authentication request: PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken [Principal=PreAuthPrincipal(certificate=null, jwToken=de.company.portal.security.jwt.validation.azd.AzdJWToken@7e84a52b, name=-::-::allowedJwtUser), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
2023-10-05T13:42:43.548+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.549+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.550+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.550+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.551+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-10-05T13:42:43.552+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.553+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-10-05T13:42:43.555+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@5773f83d]
2023-10-05T13:42:43.556+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@5773f83d] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@7fcfe065
2023-10-05T13:42:43.562+03:00 TRACE 9595 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:185)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurer$DelegateFilter.doFilter(SecurityMockMvcConfigurer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:201)
    at de.project.verification.VerificationIntegrationTest.getForCustomer_Success_WhenUserIsCustomer(VerificationIntegrationTest.java:107)
```

Comment: Update your question with full debug logs from the server, not some strange incomplete stacktrace please

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this issue. I am not sure what do you mean with "full debug logs from the server", because I run the unit tests locally, and I add them in the description

Comment: `preAuthFilter` what is this, why have you written some custom security solution, you are aware that writing custom security is bad practice?

Comment: I "inherited" the application, and my task is to update to java 17 and Spring boot 3. And actually I found the error - it was I hadn't replaced "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" with "jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate", when calling httpServletRequest.getAttribute(CERTIFICATE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the error - it was I hadn't replaced "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate" with "jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate", when calling httpServletRequest.getAttribute(CERTIFICATE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) in a custom implementation of the PreAuthFilter